# LookupError: unknown encoding: windows-874

Tags: python-3.x

We have a ticketing application with Python3.8 installed.

We have setup imap protocol with gmail domain to fetch incoming mails to create tickets.

There are some specific message thread which shows error while parsing

**LookupError: unknown encoding: windows-874**

Full traceback from terminal

File "/usr/lib/python3.8/email/contentmanager.py", line 67, in get_text_content

```
return content.decode(charset, errors=errors)
```

LookupError: unknown encoding: windows-874

How we can fix this?